# Cache OpenLayers3 Tiles server side

Tags: caching, openlayers, openlayers-3

I'm developing a website that display a map using OpenLayers3 API.
I know that most of requests will refer to a specific location so I'm wondering if it's possible to save server-side the Tiles of that region, in order to reduce calls to OpenStreetMap that sometimes is slow.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. There are several solutions

1. You can try dedicated software called more or less "map tiles proxy"

   - [Mapproxy](https://mapproxy.org)
   - [Mapcache](http://mapserver.org/mapcache/index.html)
2. You can reuse your existing web server

   You will tweak it for the intent of caching map tiles ([Nginx recipe](https://coderwall.com/p/--wgba/nginx-reverse-proxy-cache-for-openstreetmap), did not found one out of the box for Apache)
3. You can use what we call "reverse proxy" like Varnish. See [a recipe](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Varnish_setup) for this.